# ASP.NET MVC 4 problems with Facebook authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, authentication, oauth, facebook-oauth

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 I use external authentication providers - Facebook and Google. I created the app with Internet template and did not change code inside Account controller.
Now some of my users started to complain they cannot register via Facebook, while other users use it without any problems. 
I succeeded to simulate the problem. With my Facebook profile everything works OK. When I created a new profile on Facebook, I experience the same problem.
In AccountController, ExternalLoginCallback method:

```
AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
```

result.IsSuccessFull returns true for my profile, but false for the new Facebook profile I created.
Any ideas what could be wrong?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Does the new Facebook account possibly *not* have a verified email?

Comment: I clicked the link Facebook sent me to my email address and I saw a message that I confirmed the account with that email address. So I believe this is not the problem. Though, I do not now how to check if the email is confirmed directly on the Facebook page. Thanks

Comment: I created an empty application on http://dt2.azurewebsites.net. Please may I ask someone to try to login there with facebook and let me know if it works? (It works with my facebook profile but does not work with the new profile I created). It is an empty ASP.NET MVC 4 application created with Internet template. Thanks a lot

Comment: I believe all I need to do to add facebook is this code in AuthConfig.cs:             
     OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(appId: "myid", appSecret: "mysecret");

I cannot understand why it works with one profile and does not work with others :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to switch off the sandbox mode...

Comment: I'm sorry, I did probably did not make the answer clear enough. The cause of the problem was the sandbox mode switched to on. Therefore everything worked OK for testers, but not for users. Switching it to off solved the problem. Sorry again.